# How can an interface implementation be protected?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I just came across one thing in the .NET framework (v4.0) that I cannot understand:

There is the class `SortDescriptionCollection`

```
namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    public class SortDescriptionCollection : Collection<SortDescription>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        ....
        protected event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        ....
    }
}
```

implementing the Interface `INotifyCollectionChanged`:

```
public interface INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

I wanted to use the event on the class but I cannot because it's protected.

That's not the big problem because I can cast the implementation to the Interface and then use it.

But how can that be built? If I try to do with

```
class MyDerivedType : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    protected event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

so the compiler says:

> 'MyDerivedType' does not implement interface member
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged'.
>   'MyDerivedType' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

---

**EDIT:**
I don't think it's a duplicate. I was not asking *how* to compile the code above, it was the question how the .NET framework *seemed* to could do that (and obviously it couldn't)

Comment: Make it `public`. [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx): _"To implement an interface member, the corresponding member of the implementing class **must be public**, non-static, and have the same name and signature as the interface member."_

Comment: The question is how they used `protected` inside implemention. http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Base/System/ComponentModel/SortDescriptionCollection@cs/1/SortDescriptionCollection@cs thats because they added `event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged
            {
                add { this.CollectionChanged += value; }
                remove { this.CollectionChanged -= value; }
            }`

Comment: Try explicitly implementing the interfaces event: `public event INotifyCollectionChanged.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;`
Then that implementation will be called when you cast the object as the interface: `((INotifyCollectionChanged)obj).CollectionChanged();`.

Comment: The compiler is telling you the problem: you have marked it protected, when implementations of interfaces must be public. So make it public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an explicitly implemented interface event:

```
event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged
{
    add { CollectionChanged += value; }
    remove { CollectionChanged -= value; }
}
```

So it satisfies the requirements of `INotifyCollectionChanged`, but it isn't publicly visible on the class itself - perfectly valid.

This usually signalizes intent - this is not supposed to be a part of the public interface of the class. However, if you absolutely do want to access this from the outside, you can just do a cast to the interface:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCollection).CollectionChanged
```

Comment: The OP is not implementing it as an explicit interface event. It's being implemented as protected.

Comment: No. he is wondering how protected is possible. and this is the answer @DavidArno

Comment: Could not accept the answer earlier, but that's it! Didn't think of explicit implementation and the protected event irritated me

Comment: @DavidArno M.kazem Akhgary is right - you misunterstood the question. Joerg is going through the .NET source code and found a class that seems to be impossible to him, because it declares to be implementing an interface, and yet the event isn't `public`. The answer is that it's an explicit implementation, which is private (among other things). The `protected` property with the same name is then perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look, imagine that you've *implemented* the interface:

```
  SortDescriptionCollection my = new SortDescriptionCollection();

  // you can't do this (it should not compile)
  // since "CollectionChanged" is protected
  my.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => Console.Write("hello from event!");

  // however, since SortDescriptionCollection implements SortDescriptionCollection
  // you can cast to the interface
  INotifyCollectionChanged hack = my as SortDescriptionCollection;

  // wow! you can access "protected" event as if it's public one! 
  // So isolation is violated
  hack.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => Console.Write("hello from hacked event!");
```

So this *isolation violation* is the reason why you can't use `protected` methods,
events, properties when they're exposed via interfaces